# Running google datastore emulator with docker

Tags: google-app-engine, docker, google-cloud-datastore, containers

i'm trying to create a datastore emulator with docker ,
and followed the instructions here
https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator

also i used the cloud-sdk
https://hub.docker.com/r/google/cloud-sdk/

I was able to create the emulator and authenticate with it, but when i attempt to access it throght localhost:8000/datastore
it gives me "Not found" response,

How could i access the datastore data?

the command i used to create it is:

```
docker run -p 8000:8000 google/cloud-sdk gcloud beta emulators datastore start --project=pname --host-port localhost:8000 --no-store-on-disk
```

Comment: I had to instead pass `--host-port 0.0.0.0:8000` before I could reach the endpoint. The full command I used was: `docker run --rm -p 8000:8000 google/cloud-sdk:emulators gcloud --project=[project] beta emulators datastore start --host-port 0.0.0.0:8000 --no-store-on-disk`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Datastore emulator does supports only `HTTP/2`. This means that you should access the data in the emulator using support client i.e google-cloud-python, google-cloud-java e.t.c This official libraries support setting the emulator host using the environmental variables  `DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST` and `DATASTORE_PROJECT_ID`.

sample setting variables

```
export DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8000
export DATASTORE_PROJECT_ID=project-id-in-google
```

this should allow the client to access the emulator instead, when done unset the variable above to access the live datastore using:

```
unset DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST
unset DATASTORE_PROJECT_ID
```

**Notes:**

- the `DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST` can be retrieved from the running docker container as shown below

  ```
  [datastore] API endpoint: http://localhost:8000
  [datastore] If you are using a library that supports the DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST environment variable, run:
  [datastore] 
  [datastore]   export DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8000
  [datastore]
  [datastore] Dev App Server is now running.
  ```

  - `DATASTORE_PROJECT_ID` should match the project online

**tid bits**

- check emulator status `GET` request to `http://localhost:8000`, it should return `ok` if the emulator is running
- reset the emulator to remove all data by `POST` request to `http://localhost:8000/reset`